# Add same task dependency to multiple tasks in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'd like to add dependency on TaskX to multiple other tasks.

```
TaskA.dependsOn TaskX
TaskB.dependsOn TaskX
TaskC.dependsOn TaskX
TaskD.dependsOn TaskX
```

Is it possible to set it all in one call only, i.e. use a Task collection and add dependency to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume it would be:

```
[TaskA, TaskB, TaskC, TaskD]*.dependsOn TaskX
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! Could you explain what's this syntax [...]* and how it works? Thanks.

Comment: It's time to read a book on Groovy programming.  A Gradle build script is just a Groovy DSL.  I think this particular operator is called the "spread" operator.